# How do I combine several MySQL tables of varying rows?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, union, right-join

I need to compile quantities from several warehouses that update their inventories periodically. The files are automatically loaded into tables in my MySQL database, but sometimes one warehouse might have a few more or less files than the others.  I need to add them all to determine the total quantity available from the entire network.

My idea was to do:

```
    SELECT
        IFNULL(branch_01.qty,0) +
        IFNULL(branch_02.qty,0) +
        IFNULL(branch_03.qty,0) +
```

etc. through all warehouses joined as:

```
    FROM branch_01 
        JOIN branch_02
        USING (oespaced)
        JOIN branch_03 
        USING (oespaced)
```

etc. through all warehouses

I can't use LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN because sometimes one warehouse might have missing entries and sometimes another might. If a sku is missing from one branch's file, I'd prefer to still have the other branches added together, and just get a NULL, which would be converted to a 0 by the functions in the SELECT.  When I've tested different joining solutions, I also seem to be getting Cartesian numbers of rows, which confuses me further.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Just a little clarification:
We need to join 17 tables.  We're not really concerned with the sum of a column, but more the individual values.  For instance, a table might represent a list of items a,b,c,d, and list quantities of 1,2,3,4. We would have that table from several different warehouses and we would need to find a total for the entire network.  If four warehouses had those values, we would want to see a,b,c,d with 4,8,12,16 as values for the total available.

Comment: I understand why LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN won't work for you - but did you try FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: I think a FULL OUTER JOIN would be a good solution, but from what I understand, MySQL doesn't support that, and it would be implemented by doing a LEFT JOIN on the left and a RIGHT JOIN on the right.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - unfortunately, it's still very unclear. I think a specific example (table t1 has columns c1, c2 and values (v1a, v2a), (v1b, v2b), table t2 has columns... etc.) would help. Anyway, if the right solution is a FULL OUTER JOIN, and in MySQL you can't do it, then simulate it (as you mentioned yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question fully but hope my answer helps you a bit.
Are you joining many tables? So let's say 2 tables and you want to sum up the quantity column?

First of all, `JOIN` performs the cartesian product of 2(or more) tables. So you'll get so many instances that you don't wish to have; the solution to this is using the `WHERE`.

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT sum(a.qty) + sum(b.qty)
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.pk = b.fk -- this one resolves the unwanted instances
```

fk denotes foreign key and pk denotes primary key.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions @krato. I edited my original question to hopefully add a little clarification. The WHERE you suggested is probably the answer, but I don't know how to do it with our poor data, as one branch might only report a,b,c and another might only report b,c etc. If a branch doesn't report an item, we still need to know the values from the other branches instead of having them omitted from the results.